# "Class not found error" when including the file

Tags: 8, files

I have a controller inside my module as follows.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\module_name\Controller\ControllerName.
 */
namespace Drupal\module_name\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * NuSoap is required, and included here.
 */
    include 'nusoap/nusoap.php';
    class ControllerName extends ControllerBase { 

      private static $instance = NULL;
      private $session_result, $myconnection, $namespace;
      private $debug = 0;
      private $servicestatus = false;
      private $logedin = false;   
      private $appliances = array();

      /* process() retries, on error 503, $max_retries times 
       * every $recursion_timeout seconds 
       */
      private $max_retries = 15;
      private $recursion_timeout = 1;
      private $logfile = '';

      //constructor
      public function __construct ($ip, $user, $password) {
        $this->myconnection = new nusoap_client("https://" . $ip ."/sdk/");
        $this->myconnection->timeout = 10;
        $this->myconnection->useHTTPPersistentConnection();
        $this->myconnection->soap_defencoding = "UTF-8";
        $this->namespace = "urn:vim25";
        $status = $this->_Login($user, $password);
        if (!$status) {
          drupal_set_message(
            t(
              'Unable to connect to vCenter "@ip", check connection!',
              array('@ip' => $ip)
            ),
            'error'
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

and i have a folder structure inside module as **`nusoap/nusoap.php`** as follows

```
class nusoap_client extends nusoap_base  {

 var $username = '';                // Username for HTTP authentication
var $password = '';             // Password for HTTP authentication
var $authtype = '';             // Type of HTTP authentication
var $certRequest = array();     // Certificate for HTTP SSL authentication
var $requestHeaders = false;    // SOAP headers in request (text)
var $responseHeaders = '';      // SOAP headers from response (incomplete namespace resolution) (text)
var $responseHeader = NULL;     // SOAP Header from response (parsed)
var $document = '';             // SOAP body response portion (incomplete namespace resolution) (text)
var $endpoint;
var $forceEndpoint = '';
stuff ... 

}
```

As you can see it is extending the base class, but whenever I run this using the router I am getting the following error:

> Class 'Drupal\module_name\Controller\nusoap_client' not found

Is it because the wrong usage of the include files in Drupal 8? How can I include files in a controller?

As a note there are more dependent files calling the nusoap inside the nusoap folder.

Comment: This is exactly the same question as you asked earlier - either answer from the other question will fix your problem, once you understand what namespaces are and how to use them. You also have an issue related to the path you're including, but again that's just basic PHP and not related to Drupal

Comment: @clive but this is different since we are not making calls to another module but a class inside a folder from that module itself

Comment: It makes no difference - trust me, you need to learn how to use namespaces, then this will all make sense. Drupal can't help you with that, and this isn't the right place to teach a general PHP concept. To get you started: `nusoap_client` isn't in a namespace judging from the error. Put it in an appropriate namespace (`Drupal\module_name\Controller` would be the least work), or reference it as a global class with a leading backslash, e.g. `\nusoap_client`, and you'll be well on your way

Comment: @Clive is there any restriction that we should use namespaces and convert the entire folder to a module structure and call the class ?? OR can we just include from a folder like php way ??

Comment: There aren't any restrictions as such, no - you're likely to find varying opinions on whether or not you _should_ move legacy code into a module/new service/edit the code so it's in your namespace/use composer to get in the standard autoloader/etc. I'd give you a solid answer to that if I could but there isn't really one, it depends on your normal approach to this sort of thing really. Not trying to be obtuse, I know it might sound like that, but I don't want to force my opinions on to you when you're just picking this stuff up. It's bad to do that :)

Comment: It could be it is not a duplicate of the other question as @Clive says, but it is a question about plain PHP. Since those classes are not using namespaces, and you define `Drupal\module_name\Controller` as the current namespace, those classes are thought to be part of that namespace.

Comment: I would rather convert all to a Drupal service, but that is what I would do, not something that needs to be done so.

Comment: So only 2 options possible . 1) to convert that to namespace 2) use it as a service as an external library and can call from library folder ?

Comment: I fixed it , I given the namespace Drupal\module_name\Controller; on the top of the nusoap.php , solved my problem :)